# Handling gc of vector members correctly using SWIG wrappers for C++ with python

Tags: c++, vector, swig

We are using SWIG to wrap our classes in C++ and use them in Python. What we have is a method in C++ which returns a vector containing objects of our custom class, say Foo. So basically, we have wrapped the following method using SWIG:

```
std::vector<Foo> my_cpp_method(char *);
```

In the SWIG .i file, we have

```
%module wrapper
%{
...
%}
%include ...
...

namespace std {
 ...
 %template(vector_foo) vector<Foo>;
 ...
}
```

Now, here is the issue when using this with python :

```
my_list = wrapper.my_cpp_method()
o = my_list[0]

# The following works as expected
print o.value  # assume class Foo has a property called value

# Now the issue
my_list = None
gc.collect()
print o.value  # prints garbage
```

Basically, as soon as my_list is set to None, the vector is garbage collected along with its contents. When I say `o = my_list[0]` , I expect that by using copy constructor on Foo, I get a copy of the contents of `my_list[0]` (not in python, but I was hoping swig would do that for me), and thus setting list to None would not leave me with a dangling pointer.

Is there a way I can force SWIG to always invoke the copy constructor on Foo, and return me a copy on accessing the list (as a wrapped vector) members, so that I can sanely use the list returned by `my_cpp_method` like a normal python list without having to worry about dangling pointers?

EDIT: An interesting finding about iterating through a SWIG-wrapped vector in python. Just wanted to mention this since it seems that SWIG does provide a way to create copies, just not when you directly access using [] operator. 
PS: We are using this as a workaround for the above problem, but I'm hoping someone can provide a more robust and semantically correct/clean way of handling this with SWIG.

Again consider the same setup as above.

```
my_list = wrapper.my_cpp_method()
my_list[0].value = 1
print my_list[0].value  # prints 1
for o in my_list:
  o.value = 10  # Here o is actually a copy of the object and not the actual reference
# The following is very counter-intuitive in "pythonic" sense
print my_list[0].value  # still prints 1
```